# Nullpointer while Error handling with resequencer stream

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to handle an Exception in a Camel route with a resequencer stream.
I'm using Camel 2.15.2
Sometimes an exchange is not routed with my deadLetterChannel,
and in the log is a NullPointerException.
It seems the UnitOfWork of the exchange is missing sometimes.
I can reproduce it with this Classes:

The Sequencer (Processor):

```
public class Sequencer implements Processor {
    private int sequence = -1;

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.setProperty(PropertyFields.SEQUENCE_NUMBER, getNextSequenceNumber());
    }

    private synchronized int getNextSequenceNumber() {
        sequence++;
        if (sequence >= Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            sequence = 0;
        }
        return sequence;
    }

}
```

The Processor throwing the exception:

```
public class ProzessorErrorThrower implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        try {
            UnitOfWork unit = exchange.getUnitOfWork();
            System.out.println("UNIT: " + unit + " | " + exchange.getIn().getBody());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        exchange.setException(new Exception("Exception: " + exchange.getIn().getBody()));
    }

}
```

The processor for handling the exception:

```
public class ProzessorErrorHandler implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Object o = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT);
        if (o != null) {
            if (o instanceof Exception) {
                Exception e = (Exception)o;
                System.out.println("Error Handler " + exchange.getIn().getBody() + " " + e.getMessage());
            } else {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
    }

}
```

And my Method with the route and sending of messages to the route:

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

RouteBuilder builder = new RouteBuilder() {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("direct:deadLetter"));

        from("direct:deadLetter").process(new ProzessorErrorHandler());

        StreamResequencerConfig configStream = new StreamResequencerConfig(100, 3000L);

        from("direct:resequencer").
            resequence(exchangeProperty(PropertyFields.SEQUENCE_NUMBER)).
                stream(configStream).
            process(new ProzessorErrorThrower());
        from("direct:start").process(new Sequencer()).to("direct:resequencer");
    }
};

context.addRoutes(builder);

ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();

context.start();

try {
    template.sendBody("direct:start", "Test 01");
    template.sendBody("direct:start", "Test 02");
    template.sendBody("direct:start", "Test 03");

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    template.sendBody("direct:start", "Test 04");
    template.sendBody("direct:start", "Test 05");
    template.sendBody("direct:start", "Test 06");

Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    context.stop();
}
```

I get the following output:

```
UNIT: DefaultUnitOfWork | Test 01
Error Handler Test 01 Exception: Test 01
UNIT: DefaultUnitOfWork | Test 02
Error Handler Test 02 Exception: Test 02
UNIT: DefaultUnitOfWork | Test 03
Error Handler Test 03 Exception: Test 03


UNIT: null | Test 04
UNIT: DefaultUnitOfWork | Test 05
Error Handler Test 05 Exception: Test 05
UNIT: DefaultUnitOfWork | Test 06
Error Handler Test 06 Exception: Test 06
```

And in the log:

```
WARN - 11.08.2015 09:52:17.247 [Caused by: [java.lang.NullPointerException - null]] -> camel.processor.StreamResequencer
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:372)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.StreamResequencer.sendElement(StreamResequencer.java:192)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.StreamResequencer.sendElement(StreamResequencer.java:68)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.resequencer.ResequencerEngine.deliverNext(ResequencerEngine.java:280)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.resequencer.ResequencerEngine.deliver(ResequencerEngine.java:244)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.StreamResequencer$Delivery.run(StreamResequencer.java:262)
```

If i modify my code and set a new Unit of Work if it is null, the same error appears at an other message, but with no output that it was null.

The first entry in the log points to a camel code line accessing the Unit Of Work (RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:372)

I have not found something relevant for this yet.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can't UnitOfWork be null? Add a null check?

Comment: It is used internally by camel, so it has to be not null. Even if im setting it to a new DefaultUnitOfWork (if null) it sometimes happens to be null when accessed by camel.